# Googlw Sheets doeasnt work with Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have this formula in google sheets and it works correctly:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(OFFSET($A$2;0;0;ROW()-1;4);"Select D where C matches 'DK' and B matches '"&B2&"'";0);""))-COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(OFFSET($A$2;0;0;ROW()-1;4);"Select D where C matches 'H' and B matches '"&B2&"'";0);""))
```

But it goes wrong when I add ***ARRAYFORMULA***:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(OFFSET($A$2;0;0;ROW()-1;4);"Select D where C matches 'DK' and B matches '"&B2:B&"'";0);""))-COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(OFFSET($A$2;0;0;ROW()-1;4);"Select D where C matches 'H' and B matches '"&B2:B&"'";0);"")))
```

Plz help me to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `BYROW()` or `MAP()` function to make it array and spill down results. Share few sample data in the post as text.

Comment: could you take a look on Column I? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q0--BG1ABU2wR0csB51Es1gK-y1tEh3N1E2wsBT-Naw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What actually you are trying to do? Your solution would be more simple that you are thinking (I assume).

Answer (score 0):

Use `BYROW()` to spill results dynamically-

```
=BYROW(B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B)),LAMBDA(x,COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,ROW()-1,4),
"Select D where C matches 'DK' and B matches '"& x &"'",0),""))-COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,ROW()-1,4),
"Select D where C matches 'H' and B matches '"& x &"'",0),""))))
```